# Why can't the Scala compiler disambiguate a property called `type`?

Tags: scala

Every day I build another case class and wish I could define a property called `type` on it, but to do so requires using the highly annoying backtick syntax:

```
doohick.`type`
```

I get that `type` is a keyword, but why can't the compiler distinguish the keyword from the property when this `x.y` accessor syntax and avoid this syntactic wart?

Comment: Because you can always call `doohick.type` so which one would it be? the reserved property of all values or your custom method?

Comment: As Luis said, `type` is not only a keyword for defining types. It's also a property to access the type of some value.

Answer (score 2):

Because `x.type` is also a valid syntax in Scala. E.g.

```
val x = 1
val y: x.type = x //y is defined as the same type as x
```

Answer (score 1):

SwiftMango's answer and Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez's comment are technically incorrect, or at least insufficient: current `x.type` is only valid in types, your `x.type` would be valid in expressions, and the compiler can always tell which parts of code are types and which are expressions. So this wouldn't by itself be any more of a problem than e.g. `List` meaning different things in expression context (the companion object `List`) and in type context (the generic trait `List`).

But then what about `val y: x.type.type`? Would that be the type of the path `x.type` or illegal application of `.type` to a type `x.type`? If the second, how do you express the first? Why should `type` be a special case, and would allowing other keywords to be used as property/method names without backticks lead to other problems?

Given answers to these questions, you could propose the change, but I wouldn't expect it to be accepted because the win just doesn't seem that great compared to the effort and future maintenance needed for the compiler.

Comment: Yeah, I don't expect that to change, sadly. I find this to be a very frustrating wart on an otherwise near-perfect language. `type` should have been a `typeof` operator, not a property. (Or maybe `.getType()` or `.__type__` or anything else that doesn't conflict with such a commonly-used object property name.)

Comment: It's also a keyword for type aliases: `type List[A] = scala.collections.immutable.List[A]`. I don't know when singleton types appeared, but wouldn't be surprised if `.type` was used exactly because it was already a reserved word, and so couldn't be used as a member name.